# CGBitmapContextCreateImage memory leak

Tags: ios, image, memory

This line of code, which uses CGBitmapContextCreateImage from the Quartz framework, creates a major memory leak:

```
CGImageRef imgRef  = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
```

Is there any alternative method or code to replace this instead.

The entire method is as follows:

```
    - (void)captureImageWithCompletionHander:(void(^)(NSString *imageFilePath))completionHandler
    {
        dispatch_suspend(_captureQueue);
        AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
        for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
               videoConnection = connection;
               break;
            }
        }
    if (videoConnection) break;
    }
     __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
     [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
          dispatch_resume(_captureQueue);
          return;
        }
        __block NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image 1"];
     @autoreleasepool
     {
         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData options:@{kCIImageColorSpace:[NSNull null]}];
         enhancedImage = [self filteredImageUsingContrastFilterOnImage:ciImage];
         if (weakSelf.isBorderDetectionEnabled && rectangleDetectionConfidenceHighEnough(_imageDedectionConfidence))
         {
             CIRectangleFeature *rectangleFeature = [self biggestRectangleInRectangles:[[self highAccuracyRectangleDetector] featuresInImage:enhancedImage]];
             if (rectangleFeature)
             {
                 [self correctPerspectiveForImageWithFeatures:rectangleFeature];
             }
         }
         CIFilter *transform = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTransform"];
         [transform setValue:enhancedImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
         NSValue *rotation = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90 * (M_PI/180))];
         [transform setValue:rotation forKey:@"inputTransform"];
         enhancedImage = [transform outputImage];
         if (!enhancedImage || CGRectIsEmpty(enhancedImage.extent)) return;
         static CIContext *ctx = nil;
         if (!ctx)
         {
             ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace:[NSNull null]}];
         }
         CGSize bounds = enhancedImage.extent.size;
         bounds = CGSizeMake(floorf(bounds.width / 4) * 4,floorf(bounds.height / 4) * 4);
         CGRect extent = CGRectMake(enhancedImage.extent.origin.x, enhancedImage.extent.origin.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
         static int bytesPerPixel = 8;
         uint rowBytes = bytesPerPixel * bounds.width;
         uint totalBytes = rowBytes * bounds.height;
         uint8_t *byteBuffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(totalBytes);
         CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
         [ctx render:enhancedImage toBitmap:byteBuffer rowBytes:rowBytes bounds:extent format:kCIFormatRGBA8 colorSpace:colorSpace];
         CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(byteBuffer,bounds.width,bounds.height,bytesPerPixel,rowBytes,colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
         free(byteBuffer);

         CGImageRef imgRef  = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);

         CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
         CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
         saveCGImageAsJPEGToFilePath(imgRef, filePath);
         CFRelease(imgRef);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                        {
                            completionHandler(filePath);
                            dispatch_resume(_captureQueue);
                        });
         _imageDedectionConfidence = 0.0f;
     }
 }];
```

}

Comment: Could you post more code than a single line? Perhaps whole method would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by making the code a lot more lean and remove some unnecessary portions, including the above leaking line of code.

```
    - (void)captureImageWithCompletionHander:(void(^)(NSString *imageFilePath))completionHandler
    {
        dispatch_suspend(_captureQueue);
        AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
        for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections)
        {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
        }
    if (videoConnection) break;
    }
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         dispatch_resume(_captureQueue);
         return;
     }
     __block NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image 1"];
     @autoreleasepool
     {
         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];imageData=nil;
         CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(img.size.width, img.size.height);
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
         [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
         UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
         CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:newImage];             
         enhancedImage = [self filteredImageUsingContrastFilterOnImage:ciImage];
         if (weakSelf.isBorderDetectionEnabled && rectangleDetectionConfidenceHighEnough(_imageDedectionConfidence))
         {
             CIRectangleFeature *rectangleFeature = [self biggestRectangleInRectangles:[[self highAccuracyRectangleDetector] featuresInImage:enhancedImage]];
             if (rectangleFeature)
             {
                 enhancedImage = [self correctPerspectiveForImage:enhancedImage withFeatures:rectangleFeature];
             }
         }
         if (!enhancedImage || CGRectIsEmpty(enhancedImage.extent)) return;
         CGRect rect;
         rect = [enhancedImage extent];
         if (!ctx)
         {
             ctx = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace:[NSNull null]}];
         }             
         CGImageRef imgRef = [ctx createCGImage:enhancedImage fromRect:rect];             
         saveCGImageAsJPEGToFilePath(imgRef, filePath);             
         CFRelease(imgRef);             
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                        {
                            completionHandler(filePath);
                            dispatch_resume(_captureQueue);
                        });
         _imageDedectionConfidence = 0.0f;
     }
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used CGBitmapContextCreateImage() to create a CGImage, but you haven't released that CGImage.

once you got the UIImage release the CGImageRef that will help you

Get the image from

```
CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext);
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
CGImageRelease(imgRef);
```